# How can I transpose those data putting the year as first column?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

Here's some data from my np array:

```
 [2002  675  456  111]
 [2003  682  472  101]
 [2004  731  497  129]]
```

I'd like to create a matrix where the first column is the list ages=range(15,50) and the first row is the year (2002,2003,...)

Comment: First part of the solution
my_data = np.genfromtxt(fileFertility, delimiter=',',dtype=int,usecols=(0,1,2,3))

my_data=my_data.transpose()

Comment: first problem: I have more rows in the ages than in the np array

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module or the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library to perform that task. But if you want to have a quick test maybe you'll find this code useful:

```
data = np.asarray([[2002, 675, 456, 111],
                   [2003, 682, 472, 101],
                   [2004, 731, 497, 129]])
ages = np.arange(15, 50, dtype=data.dtype)

arr = np.zeros((1 + ages.size, 1 + data.shape[0]), dtype=data.dtype)
arr[0:data.shape[1], 1:] = data.T
arr[1:, 0] = ages
```

And this is what you get:

```
>>> arr
array([[   0, 2002, 2003, 2004],
       [  15,  675,  682,  731],
       [  16,  456,  472,  497],
       [  17,  111,  101,  129],
       [  18,    0,    0,    0],
       [  19,    0,    0,    0],
       [  20,    0,    0,    0],
       ...,
       [  47,    0,    0,    0],
       [  48,    0,    0,    0],
       [  49,    0,    0,    0]])
```

Hope this helps